# Finding all viable paths between two nodes

Tags: javascript, algorithm, path-finding

I have a set of paths that join nodes and need to be able to enter two nodes to see if there are any viable paths (and count, if more than one). On top of this, I need to track the route. A simplified example can be found in this image below.

[image]

The image is essentially this array:

```
mappings = [
        [1,3],
        [3,6],
        [6,11],
        [11,12],
        [3,7],
        [7,10],
        [2,4],
        [4,5],
        [4,8],
        [5,9],
        [9,10]
    ];
```

I currently have a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fHY8W/9/) where I can enter 2 and 10, and it will tell me the correct path (2 > 4 > 5 > 9 > 10). However, entering 1 and 10 doesn't produce a path, because my rudimentary algorithm isn't smart enough. Any tips on modifying mine, or an existing algorithm I can use to tackle this problem?

Ideally, I would have the following input/output:

```
Input: 1,10 
Output: 1 > 3 > 7 > 10

Input: 1,11
Output: 1 > 3 > 6 > 11
```

Comment: Uhm have you tried [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) ? And you need to display **all** paths? so other question will be is there any cycle in the map?

Comment: What kind of data structure are you using to store these values?

Comment: @PhamTrung yes, there may be cycles, i'll look into BFS. Mercury, they currently exist on a database as id's so they can be pulled down and handled in JS any kind of way really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can use BFS, setting one of the input nodes as the root of the algorithm and observe if the second one was visited after the execution. Implementation is quite straightforward.

On the other hand, finding all possible paths in graph which may contain cycles is quite hard (NP-hard). The number of possible paths is exponential. Even worse, if graph is not Directed Acyclic graph (and contain cycles) there may be infinite number of paths between two nodes.

Comment: Looking into BFS as we speak, thankfully these are user-created diagrams and while I understand the idea behind an infinite number of paths, realistically there will never even be more than ~100 (Nor more than 100 nodes)

Comment: @Matús Dúbrava Could you please enlarge a bit on the NP-hardness? To my understanding, as soon as cycles are permitted, the number of paths may be unlimited, which means that output size is potentially unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following recurrence: the set of paths from `A` to `B` is the same as the set of edges from `A` to all its neighbors `N`, followed by all paths from `N` to `B`.

To avoid looping, you must check that `N` is not already on the path. You can do this by marking the nodes as you visit them, and unmarking when you backtrack.

In your example, all paths from 2 to 10 are all edges from 2 to `N` followed by all paths from `N` to 10, i.e. 2 > 4 followed by all paths from 4 to 10.

The paths from 4 to 10 are 4 > 8 followed by all paths from 8 to 10, and 4 > 5 followed by all paths from 5 to 10; 4 > 2 is forbidden as 2 is already in the path from 2.

The paths from 8 to 10 form an empty set, as the only neighbor of 8, namely 4, is already in the path from 2.

The paths from 5 to 10 are 5 > 9 followed by all paths from 9 to 10; 5 > 4 is forbidden.

The paths from 9 to 10 are 9 > 10 followed by the empty path (target reached); 9 > 5 is forbidden.

The algorithm can be written recursively as

```
Visit(A, B, Path)::=
    if A == B:
        # Target reached
        Output(Path)
        return

    # Mark the node
    Mark(A)

    # Try all unmarked neighbors
    for all neighbors N of A:
        if not Marked(A):
            # Recurse
            Visit(N, B, Path + N)

    # Backtrack
    Unmark(A)

Visit(A, B, Empty)
```